# How can I merge a set and array into vector in c++

Tags: c++

When I execute this code, it throws me: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
What should I change the code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int *even=new int[100];

    int *temp=new int[100];

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        even[i]=2*i+2;
        temp[i]=2*i+1;  
    }
    set <int,less<int> > odd(temp,temp+100);

    vector <int> vec;

    merge(even, even+100,odd.begin(), odd.end(), vec.begin());

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){ cout<<"merged vector is:" <<vec[i]<<endl; 

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Resize the vector to the sum of the sizes of odd and even or use std::back_inserier

Comment: curious why you're allocating raw arrays instead of just using `std::vector`s for temporary storage. If the allocation of `temp` fails then `even` will leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

`vec` is empty, and `merge` doesn't (can't) change the size of it through a regular iterator.
This is why `std::back_inserter` was invented – it's an "iterator" that uses `push_back` to add elements:

```
merge(even, even+100, odd.begin(), odd.end(), back_inserter(vec));
```

Since you know the size of the result, you can also "pre-size" `vec` and use your current method:

```
vector <int> vec(100 + odd.size());
merge(even, even+100, odd.begin(), odd.end(), vec.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

change `vector<int> vec`;

to`vector <int> vec (100+odd.size());`